# Does the null character get automatically inserted?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, initialization, string-literals

Is the C++ compiler supposed to automatically insert the null character after the end of the char array?  The following prints "Word".  So does the C++ compiler automatically insert a null character at the last position in the array?

```
int main()
{
    char x[] = {'W', 'o', 'r', 'd'};
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is new to c++ and reading this, using `std::string` will save you from a lot of undefined behaviour hassles like this.

Answer (score 6):

No, it doesn't. Your array `x` has only 4 elements. You are passing `std::cout` a pointer to `char`, which is not the beginning of a null-terminated string. This is undefined behaviour.

As an example, on my platform, similar code printed `Word?`, with a spurious question mark.

Comment: I ran the code too and now I’m stuck with chronic nasal demons. Thanks. :(

Answer (score 5):

In C/C++ string literals are automatically appended with terminating zero. So if you will write for example

```
char x[] = "Word";
```

then the size of the array will be equal to 5 and the last element of the array will contain '\0'.

When the following record is used as you showed

```
char x[] = {'W', 'o', 'r', 'd'};
```

then the compiler allocates exactly the same number of elements as the number of the initializers. That is in this case the array will have only 4 elements.

However if you would write the following way

```
char x[5] = {'W', 'o', 'r', 'd'};
```

then the fifth element will contain the terminating zero because it has no corresponding initializer and will be zero-initialized.

Also take into account that the following record is valid in C but invalid in C++

```
char x[4] = "Word";
```

Answer (score 3):

That is undefined behavior, and it printed "Word" as it might also have crashed.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. You yourself have to do that if you want to use it as a string or you want to use library functions for strings for that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. If you want it inserted automatically, use a string constant:

```
const char *x = "Word";
//OR 
std::string const s = "Word";
const char *x = s.c_str();
//OR
char x[] = { "Word" }; //using the C++11 brace initializer syntax.
```

The simplest way to verify this is to look at the memory address for x using a debugger and monitor it and the next few bytes following it. Stop the debugger after the initialization and examine the memory contents.

Answer (score 1):

No, in this case you are just creating a non-null terminated array. In-case of a read based on null termination. Your program won't stop as it wouldn't find the null at last.

```
char x[] = "Word";
```

In this case 5 bytes would be allocated for x. Null at the end.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to use the `char` array as a string use this form of the initializer

```
char x[] = { "Word" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not guaranteed, it seems my implementation always adds a `\0` even if I am not requested.

I tested `noNull[2]` is always `\0`

```
char noNull[] = {'H', 'i'};
for (int i = 2; i < 5; ++i) {
    if (noNull[i] == '\0') {
        std::cout << "index " << i << " is null" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "index " << i << " is not null" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

output

```
index 2 is null
index 3 is not null
index 4 is not null
```